# On a proof of a lemma by Titchmarsh/Bohr and Landau

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series

In the Titchmarsh treatise "The Theory of the Riemann zeta function", at page 159 of the first edition, we have a lemma at paragraph 8.7.
I joined an image

[image: Page 159]

My question is about the proof of the lemma and on the condition "let every m with b_m <>0 be prime to every n with c_n <>0. What is the signification of the condition ? Is it a normal product ?
The text of Bohr and Landau « Nachtrag zu unsere Abhandlungen aus den Jahrgäng 1910 und 1923 », Göttinger  Nachrichten 1924, 168-172
Translated from Deutsch to English by Titchmarsh say exactly :
"in $g(s)h(s) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{d_r}{r^s}$ entsteht nämich jedes $d_r \ne 0$ nur aus einem product $b_n c_m$ mit $nm=r$".
So "in $g(s)h(s) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{d_r}{r^s}$, each $d_r \ne 0$ is from only a product $b_n c_m$ with $nm=r$".
So there is a slight alteration of the original paper. Can you give me a full proof of the lemma ? Thanks you very much.

Comment: The normal English interpretation would be that for every $n, m$ with $b_n \ne 0, c_m \ne 0$, we must have that $m$ and $n$ have no common divisors: $\gcd(n,m) = 1$. If other words, if $b_n \ne 0$ and $\gcd(n,m) >1$, then $c_m = 0$.

Comment: Yes. I have also this interpretation but the question is "why this condition is necessary  for the validity of the lemma" ?

Comment: The question is solved.

Comment: The question is solved. When you calculate the product $\sum\frac{d_r^2}{r^{2\sigma}} +2\sum_n\sum_m \frac{d_n d_m}{n^{\sigma+it} m^{\sigma-it}}$ the condition appears. The second term is $0$ if $gcd(d_n, d_m) =1$